# JRuby: custom test gem installing to ruby not jruby

Tags: rubygems, jruby

I have jruby installed at `/home/david/apps/jruby` and is not set in .bash_profile. I do have ruby set at `/home/david/apps/ruby/bin` in .bash_profile.

I created a hello world gem.

```
/home/david/apps/jruby/bin/jruby -S rake install
test 0.0.1 built to pkg/test-0.0.1.gem
test (0.0.1) installed
```

then

```
/home/david/apps/jruby/bin/jruby -S gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.22)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
em-proxy (0.1.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10 java)
http_parser (0.1.3)
json (1.5.0 java)
json-jruby (1.5.0 java)
macaddr (1.6.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0 java)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rspec (2.8.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
sources (0.0.1)
systemu (2.2.0)
uuid (2.3.5)
```

Not there but it does show up with

david@linux-8h1y:~/projects/greyfox/test> ruby -S gem list --local

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...             
test (0.0.1)
...
```

What am I missing? It is driving me nuts. Please do not recommend RVM, I have had nothing but headaches with that hacked-up pile of crap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `/home/david/apps/jruby/bin/jruby -S rake install` try doing a
`/home/david/apps/jruby/bin/jruby -S gem install pkg/test-0.0.1.gem` :)